# Increase the length of username field in django auth_user table using postgres database

Tags: python, django

I am working on django project and want to increase the max length of username field in auth_user table.
I tried to change it from database and when i did it returned a error

```
ERROR:  must be owner of relation auth_user
```

How can i resolve it, or is there any another easy option ?

Comment: You will have to create custom user https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: actually project is going to complete and i have written huge code, so at this state if i change default auth_user table, won't it effect on my existing code ?

Comment: It depends on how you have written your code. If for example every time you needed `User` model you have used `from django.auth.contrib import get_user_model`  helper function, then you shouldn't have any problems. But in any case yeah it will affect your exsting code, but on how drastic this effects are depends on your code.